# Problems when fetching source code from a webpage

Tags: android, html, character-encoding

Im trying getting source code from this [site](http://livetv.sx/en/allupcomingsports/1/)
Please see link above

I using this code to fetch source:

```
        in = DownloaderUtil.fetch(linkToFetch);;
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in,"ISO-8859-1"));
        str = new StringBuilder();
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            str.append(line+"\n"); 
            count ++;
        }
```

At the first time, I could able to get the good source code without any error.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"....something like this
```

But the second time or sometimes, I could not get the right source code from this page, it contains all of strange character.

I already think that this site is special and each time I request it change the Encoding charset. But I try with UTF-8, ISO-8859-15, I still get the same result.
Have u face with the same problems as me.
Could u help me to fix it or give me the way to get the right source code from this site?
Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Finnally I found the solution on my self.
The reason is this site compress source source code GZIP so I need to decompress before using.

```
InputStream instream = response.getEntity().getContent();
Header contentEncoding = response.getFirstHeader("Content-Encoding");
if (contentEncoding != null && contentEncoding.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
    instream = new GZIPInputStream(instream);
}
```

Thanks!